# List of objects does not work as expected

Tags: c#

I want to create a list of objects. I created a class that I will use with my list of objects

```
public class DataSet 
{
    public string[] setOfValues = new string[5];
}
```

When I used this class in code, I am unable to erase an array of strings, because the list of objects also gets altered.

```
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DataSet> myListOfDataSets = new List<DataSet>();
        DataSet mySet = null;
        string[] myArrayOfStrings = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};

        mySet = new DataSet();
        mySet.setOfValues = myArrayOfStrings;
        myListOfDataSets.Add(mySet);

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        { //this command wipes off the values from myListOfDataSets
            myArrayOfStrings[k] = string.Empty; 
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to reuse myArrayOfStrings without affecting myListOfDataSets.
Once I added a new object to myListOfDataSets, I don't understand how later commands applied to a different item change the content of this list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*They are the **same** item!*

Class and array variables in C# are just references. The actual object is off in the heap somewhere. All the assignments you make are just moving references around for the same object.

What you can do is *replace* the reference:

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<DataSet> myListOfDataSets = new List<DataSet>();
    DataSet mySet = null;
    string[] myArrayOfStrings = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};

    mySet = new DataSet();
    mySet.setOfValues = myArrayOfStrings;
    myListOfDataSets.Add(mySet);

    //sets variable to **new** object instance, so it no
    // longer refers to the old one
    myArrayOfStrings = new string[] {"","","","",""};

    //This whole section is now redundant
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    { //this command wipes off the values from myListOfDataSets
        myArrayOfStrings[k] = string.Empty; 
    }
}
```

And you can further significantly shorten all this code like so:

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myListOfDataSets = new List<DataSet>
    {
      new DataSet() {setOfValues = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"} }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Joel. I found an alternative way (I assigned each element of mySet from myArrayOfStrings in a for loop), but clearly your code is much better.

Answer (score 1):

So what is happening is that you are setting 'mySet's setOfValues to the array located at myArrayOfStrings' address. This means that mySet's setOfValues is not a separate object than the one that you're assigning it to, but the same one. That is why when you update myArrayOfStrings, mySet's values change too.

To get the results your looking for, loop through myArrayOfStrings and set mySet.setOfValues[i] to myArrayOfStrings[i] and you should be set!

Comment: Hi Andrew. That's exactly what I've done before I read Joel's answer (looping through each element) and it worked. Thanks for explanations.